# How to Monitor health of AWS cloudwatch agents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard, health-check

I have hundreds of EC2 servers runnin cloudwatch agents in them.

I would like to have a monitoring mechanism to monitor hralthcheck of cloudwatch agents.

And show the health as green or red on a dashboard.

Is there a cloud native approach available for this?

Can I use Quicksight for this? How can I generate datasets for quicksight in this case?

Comment: Hi Biju, have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using procstat...

"The procstat plugin enables you to collect metrics from individual processes. It is supported on Linux servers and on servers running Windows Server 2012 or later."